# JLayeredPane image not showing up

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have an Image and all I want is to pack this Image into a JLabel and add it to my JLayeredPane to layer multiple images later.
It worked with one Image without a JLayeredPane, but when using the JLayeredPane I only see my border.
I have to layer multiple Images so ypu can configurate a Pizza and see your customised Pizza.

```
package view;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * ImagePanel used to scale and display an image
 */

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

/**
 * Setup an ImagePanel, get the image, scale it and set it as a label to display it
 */
public ImagePanel(){

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your Pizza"));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/pizzaboden.png"));
    JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(icon);
    layeredPane.add(imgLabel);
    add(layeredPane);

}
}
```

Reading the image works, this is the way I read it earlier and it worked fine:

My datafield

```
private ImageIcon imageIcon;
private ImageIcon scaledImageIcon;
private JLabel imageLabel;
private Image image;
private Image scaledImage;
```

My Constructor

```
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/pizzaboden.png"));
    image = imageIcon.getImage();
    scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(280, 280, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    scaledImageIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
    imageLabel = new JLabel(scaledImageIcon);
    add(imageLabel);
```

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KEC.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you add something to a JLayeredPane, you need to specify where the component is being added in the X/Y dimension as well as where in the layered dimension, as per the [JLayeredPane tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), and you don't do this. You also need to give the JLabel a size since it's preferred size is not respected by the JLayeredPane. Something like

```
imgLabel.setSize(imgLabel.getPreferredSize());
imgLabel.setPosition(0, 0);
layeredPane.add(imgLabel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
```

may be adequate.

Also, have you tested independent of this current program to make sure that the image is being read in appropriately? Also, you're adding to a FlowLayout using JPanel -- are you sure that you want to do this? Perhaps better would be to give your ImagePanel a BorderLayout.

---

Note that if I were doing something like this, show multiple overlapping images in a Swing GUI, I wouldn't use a JLayeredPane but instead would draw images (BufferedImages) in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of a single drawing JPanel, and I'd add and remove images from the GUI when desired, then call `repaint()` on the drawing JPanel.

For instance, if you give the drawing JPanel an ArrayList of images like so:

```
private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can draw any images held by this list by iterating through the list in the paintComponent method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Image image : images) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

And you can add and remove images easily:

```
public void clearImages() {
    images.clear();
    repaint();
}

public void removeImage(Image image) {
    images.remove(image);
    repaint();
}

public void addImage(Image image) {
    images.add(image);
    repaint();
}
```

For example, here is test-of-concept code that you can run that demonstrates what I mean:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleImages extends JPanel {
    private static final String BULLS_EYE_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "commons/thumb/3/36/Roundel_of_the_Serbian_Air_Force_1915.svg/"
            + "300px-Roundel_of_the_Serbian_Air_Force_1915.svg.png";
    private static final String CHINESE_CHAR_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/"
            + "wikipedia/commons/1/1a/%E9%9D%91-red.png";
    private static final String HOCKY_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "commons/thumb/e/eb/Ice_hockey_pictogram.svg/"
            + "300px-Ice_hockey_pictogram.svg.png";
    private static final String[] LABELS = {"Bulls Eye", "Chinese Character", "Hockey"};
    private static final String[] IMAGE_PATHS = {BULLS_EYE_PATH, CHINESE_CHAR_PATH, HOCKY_PATH};
    private Map<String, Image> imageMap = new HashMap<>();
    private List<JCheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

    public MultipleImages() throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_PATHS.length; i++) {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMAGE_PATHS[i]);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
            imageMap.put(LABELS[i], img);
        }

        ActionListener checkBoxListener = e -> {
            imagePanel.clearImages();
            for (JCheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes) {
                if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                    String label = checkBox.getActionCommand();
                    imagePanel.addImage(imageMap.get(label));
                }
            }
            imagePanel.repaint();
        };
        JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (String label : LABELS) {
            JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(label);
            checkBox.setActionCommand(label);
            checkBoxes.add(checkBox);
            checkBoxPanel.add(checkBox);
            checkBox.addActionListener(checkBoxListener);
        }
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        rightPanel.add(checkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(imagePanel);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multiple Images");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            frame.getContentPane().add(new MultipleImages());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 300;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.WHITE;
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public ImagePanel() {
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Image image : images) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public void clearImages() {
        images.clear();
        repaint();
    }

    public void removeImage(Image image) {
        images.remove(image);
        repaint();
    }

    public void addImage(Image image) {
        images.add(image);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote and I also tried to follow the tutorial way earlier before I answered it here, but I don't really get it. So I tried this now: `imgLabel.setSize(imgLabel.getPreferredSize());
        imgLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(0);
        imgLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(0);`

Comment: @RobinSchneider: please no code in comments. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50456806/edit) if you need to show new code. Also, and again, please tell us if you're reading the image in and displaying it in a simpler application, say by displaying the ImageIcon in a JOptionPane.

Comment: @RobinSchneider: please see edit for a possible "better way"